Excluding `type` when serialising an object with ObjectMapper
I am serializing an instance of class Foo to send to pubsub. I am using Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize the instance to string before sending it as a payload.
    @Bean(name = "gcpObjectMapper")
    public ObjectMapper gcpMenuSyncMessageObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder
                .createXmlMapper(false)
                .build();

        // Some other custom configuration for supporting Java 8 features
        objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

        objectMapper.setDefaultTyping(new StdTypeResolverBuilder()
                .init(JsonTypeInfo.Id.NONE, null)
                .inclusion(JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY)
                .typeProperty(null)
                .typeIdVisibility(false));

        return objectMapper;
    }

This bean is injected in my component which handles the publishing of messages:
  private ByteString convertPayload(@NotNull Foo payload) throws BusinessRuntimeException {
        try {
            String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload);
            return ByteString.copyFromUtf8(jsonString);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Error converting payload to JSON", e);
            throw new BusinessRuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

However, the type key (the class name of the instance) is still included in the string-serialized JSON. How can I configure the object mapper not to include the type info for the object?

You can use the disable() method of ObjectMapper class, and pass the serialization feature SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE to disable the inclusion of the class name during serialization.

Feature that can be enabled to make root value (usually JSON Object but can be any type) wrapped within a single property JSON object, where key as the "root name", as determined by annotation introspector (esp. for JAXB that uses @XmlRootElement.name) or fallback (non-qualified class name). Feature is mostly intended for JAXB compatibility.

objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);

Your snippet would look like this
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
// Disable WRAP_ROOT_VALUE
objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE);


To achieve this , you need to disable the default typing behaviour by adding this :
objectMapper.deactivateDefaultTyping();

Updated Code:
@Bean(name = "gcpObjectMapper")
public ObjectMapper gcpMenuSyncMessageObjectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder
            .createXmlMapper(false)
            .build();

    // Some other custom configuration for supporting Java 8 features
    objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

  objectMapper.deactivateDefaultTyping();

    return objectMapper;
}

